# Javascript add to string after http://?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a url http://blah.com and I want to take the url and add something to the front of the blah.com

Which would result in http://something_blah.com

Is this possible with javascript?

Regards,

Comment: You mean like string manipulation? https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String#Methods_2

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
var url = "http://blah.com"
var new_url = url.replace(/^http:\/\//, "http://something_")
```

`/^http:\/\//` is a [regular expression](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/regexp), a type of object used to match patterns of strings. This allows me to specify (using `^`) that I only want to replace `https://` if it occurs at the start of the string.

If you know the string is going to start with "http://", you could also just use a string as the replacement target because [`.replace()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) only replaces the first match by default.

```
var new_url = url.replace("http://", "http://something_")
```

If you want something that will work with any protocol, HTTP, HTTPS, FTP or whatever, you can use a regular expression that "captures" that part of the original string and uses it in the replacement.

```
var new_url = url.replace(/^([a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9\.\+\-]*):\/\//, "$1://something_")
```

Breaking this particular pattenern down piece by piece:

- `^` it must begin at the start of the string
- `(` start a "capturing" group
- `[a-zA-Z]` match any letters
- `[a-zA-Z0-9\.\+\-]*` followed by any letters, digits, periods, plusses or hyphens, repeated any number of times.
- `)` end the capturing group
- `:\/\/` match `"://"`

Answer (score 2):

Use [Javacript Replace](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_replace.asp)

```
myString = "http://blah.com";
myString.replace("http://", "http://something_");
```

Comment: You might want to edit this answer: `String` is a built-in constructor. :-)

Answer (score 0):

This one works with http or https

```
    var url = window.location.href;
    var i = url.indexOf ('://') + 3;
    var newUrl = url.substring(0, i) + 'something_' + url.substring (i, url.length);
    window.location.href = newUrl;
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need jQuery. Use split().

```
var text = 'something_';
var a = "http://blah.com";
var b = a.split("http://")[1];
var c = "http://"+text+b;
alert(c);
```